# SQL Statement Error table to table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying insert table data into another table,

But I'm getting the following error:

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 4
>   Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK___4__10'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tbl_Diagnosis_Table'.

Appears to be a duplicate primary key between both tables. Both tables have the same fields and data types, different data. What query can resolve this issue?

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Diagnosis_Table
   SELECT * 
   FROM tbl_Holding_Diagnosis_Table

INSERT INTO tbl_Diagnosis_Table(Code, [Description], Comments, Discontinued)
   (SELECT 
       Code, [Description], Comments, Discontinued
    FROM 
       tbl_Holding_Diagnosis_Table);
```

Comment: Is it OK if the inserted values get new primary keys? And is the primary key an AutoNumber?

Comment: No it's not ok because they link up with other tables.

Comment: What's the primary key on `tbl_Diagnosis_Table`? Is there a primary key on `tbl_Holding_Diagnosis_Table`?

Comment: Then the only way to solve this is to remove the uniqueness requirement of the primary key field, but you'll probably need to add a new field to normalize and differentiate the inserted data in the table.

Comment: Also, that constraint name is not descriptive. You might consider renaming it so it's easier to tell which table it belongs to.

Comment: AdamV: They both have the same fields, exact data types, and same primary key.  One table is a holding table, other original.  jbarker2160: inserting a new field??? How would that work?

Comment: @jbarker2160 you can't "remove the uniqueness" of a primary key. You would have to remove the primary key and find (an)other column(s).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Code` is the primary key this should eliminate the duplicate rows from the insert:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Diagnosis_Table (Code, [Description], Comments, Discontinued)
SELECT Code, [Description], Comments, Discontinued
FROM tbl_Holding_Diagnosis_Table
WHERE tbl_Holding_Diagnosis_Table.Code NOT IN 
    (SELECT Code FROM tbl_Diagnosis_Table)
```

If the primary key is some other column, or a composite key, you might need to use a join instead.

You might want to look at the [MERGE statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) if you want to update existing rows and only insert new.

Comment: Tried it, error message: Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: The user might also want to overwrite what's already in `tbl_Diagnosis_Table` if the `Code`s match; you'd want to do that before copying in new rows.

Comment: @AdamV True, my answer doesn't take that into account. A `merge into`statement seems more appropriate.

Comment: @sclass What column is the primary key then if the error is the same as before?

Comment: @sclass Hmm that's odd then. The rows with existing code values should be excluded. Was the error still about a primary key violation?

Comment: @sclass - what columns are string or binary? Are the column sizes the same in both tables?

Comment: @AdamV - strings and datetime. Column sizes are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need a WHERE with an IN Clause To filter the records to insert, but first you need to know wich fields form the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're saying is correct i.e. all the values are unique, it leaves only one option. Make sure that if there is an identity column in table tbl_diagnosis_table, you are setting the IDENTITY_INSERT to ON on this table and providing values manually in the select. It might have been possible that the seed and increment was reset in the past. In case you were wrong, you have to use a where clause as suggested by others.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest using a [Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) query to do insert or update until I noticed the two inserts in the sample code both do the same insert.  The error also says the error is on line 4 which is where the second insert occurs.  If the two inserts aren't two examples of the problematic code, then the resolution may be as simple as removing one of the inserts.

Otherwise the other answers are correct, the duplicate rows need to be filtered and the IDENTITY_INSERT has to be turned on for the table.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_Diagnosis_Table ON -- if it is necessary to have the same primary key
MERGE tbl_Diagnosis_Table  AS target
  USING (SELECT Code, Description, Comments, Discontinued FROM tbl_Holding_Diagnosis_Table) AS source (Code, Description, Comments, Discontinued)
  ON (target.Code = source.Code)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE SET Description = source.Description, 
     Comments = source.Comments,
     Discontinued = source.Discontinued
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (Code, Description, Comments, Discontinued)
  VALUES (source.Code, source.Description, source.Comments, source.Discontinued)
END; -- missing semicolons causes errors
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_Diagnosis_Table OFF
```

Do your homework though.  There are some very good reasons not to use Merge.

- [Use Caution with SQL Server's MERGE Statement](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)
- [Indexed views and Merge](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/02/t-sql-queries/another-merge-bug)
- [Optimizing Merge Statement Performance](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879317(v=sql.105).aspx)